# Setting classpath at runtime

Tags: java, jar, libraries

I have a java file called `EXICodec.java` which performs various operations thanks to the jar `exificient.jar`. They are in the same folder.

Here is the structure of the file `EXICodec.java` :

```
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
[...]
import com.siemens.ct.exi.helpers.DefaultEXIFactory;

public class EXICodec {
    /*
     * Main
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        for (int i=0;i < args.length ; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println(args[i]);    
        }
    }
    /*
     * Attributes
     */
    [...]

    /*
     * Constructor (default)
     */
    public EXICodec()
    {[...]}

    /*
     * Methods using import from exificient.jar
     */
    [...]
```

When I compile, I run the following command : (and it works)

> javac -cp exificient.jar EXICodec.java

And then I want to execute:

> java -cp exificient.jar EXICodec

but I have the following error :

```
Error : java could not find or load main class EXICodec
```

Am I missing some basic thing ? I thought it was link to the package name. I had one and place the file in the proper folder but I got the same problems : it compiles but does not run.

Comment: Is there a package in which `EXICodec` resides? You need to supply the fully qualified class name of the main class to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the location of `EXICodec.class` to the classpath.

Something along the lines of

```
java -cp "exificient.jar:." EXICodec
```

(assuming you're on Unix)

Answer (score 1):

Add the current directory (that contains the file `EXICodec.class`) to the classpath:

```
java -cp exificient.jar;. EXICodec
```

The current directory is indicated by `.`

If you are using a Unix-like operating system (Mac OS X or Linux) instead of Windows, use `:` instead of `;` as the path separator:

```
java -cp exificient.jar:. EXICodec
```